# XCTest: Disable animations on iOS Safari browser

Tags: xctest, xcuitest, xcuiautomation

I am working on XCUITest to automate some features in Safari browser in iPhone.
Intermittently, I am seeing following logs and automation is stuck.

```
t =   504.16s         Wait for app to idle
t =   625.29s         App animations complete notification not received, will attempt to continue.
t =   625.30s         Synthesize event
t =   625.67s         Wait for app to idle
```

All the answers on internet suggest to use `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)`. I tried this solution, but this has not helped much.

My question is: Does `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` disable the animations only in apps or will this also be applicable for websites in Safari browser?
If not, are there any other workarounds?

Ref - [Xcode 8 UI Testing Taking Very Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983184/xcode-8-ui-testing-taking-very-long)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in [Disabling waiting for idle state in UI testing of iOS apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277026/disabling-waiting-for-idle-state-in-ui-testing-of-ios-apps).
`TestBase` is my base class extended from `XCTestCase`

```
private func disableWaitForIdle() {
    if !TestBase.swizzledOutIdle {
        let original = class_getInstanceMethod(objc_getClass("XCUIApplicationProcess") as? AnyClass, Selector(("waitForQuiescenceIncludingAnimationsIdle:")))
        let replaced = class_getInstanceMethod(type(of: self), #selector(TestBase.replace))!
        method_exchangeImplementations(original!, replaced)
        TestBase.swizzledOutIdle = true
    }
}

@objc func replace() {
    return
}
```

Usage:

```
override func setUp() {
        Self.logger.info("Running test method setup before \(self.name)...")
        disableWaitForIdle()
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
}
```